# How to re-use python scripts (in Pycharm) across multiple environments

Tags: python, pycharm, environment-variables, environment

I've built automation scripts in python (using Pycharm) to validate the APIs in QA region. I have used many database connection strings as part of my scripts and now I'm wondering if I could re-use the same set of scripts to validate the STG region without much maintenance.

Is there a way to handle the connection strings that I use in the scripts separately per each environment and just by passing the environment variable the script should fetch the connection strings by that environment and execute them. Currently, they are hardcoded in my script meaning I have to update the connection strings manually every time I want to switch between environments.

**What I have:** Scripts in python with connection strings of QA region If I would like to run in STG, I have manually update the connection strings with of STG region and execute the scripts. If I have to re-run them in QA, again I have to update them to QA from STG.

**What I'm looking for:** is a way to handle the connection strings separately per environment and be able to re-use the scripts by just passing the environment variable.

please let me know for any more details...

Comment: Sounds like you just need to read the connection string from the environment: `os.environ.get('DB_CONNECTION_STRING', 'some default value if variable does not exist')`